# Mapping nHibernate One Table to Class & Sub Classes

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Trying to map a Order Class with two identical sub classes and Getting the following error

```
Could not find a getter for property 'RatingCriteria1' in class 'ORM.Entities.Enquiry.EnquiryOrder'
```

Basically I have one table in database with alot of columns. 12 columns are rating related

BuyerRatingCriteria1,BuyerRatingCriteria2, BuyerRatingCriteria3, BuyerRatingCriteria4, BuyerRatingCriteria5, BuyerRatingCriteriaComments

And

SupplierRatingCriteria1, SupplierRatingCriteria2, SupplierRatingCriteria3, SupplierRatingCriteria4, SupplierRatingCriteria5, SupplierRatingCriteriaComments

I want to simplify these into two subclasses on the so that i have

```
Order.SupplierRating.Criteria1
```

and

```
Order.BuyerRating.Criteria1
```

for example

```
public class EnquiryOrder : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateOrdered { get; set; }

    public virtual string PONumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SONumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Rating SupplierRatings { get; set; }
    public virtual Rating BuyerRatings { get; set; }

}

public class Rating : Entity
{
    public virtual int RatingCriteria1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int RatingCriteria2 { get; set; }
    public virtual int RatingCriteria3 { get; set; }
    public virtual int RatingCriteria4 { get; set; }
    public virtual int RatingCriteria5 { get; set; }
    public virtual string RatingCriteriaComment { get; set; }

}
```

Mapping I thought would be as easy as this

```
    public EnquiryOrderMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("EnquiryOrderId");
        Map(x => x.DateOrdered);

        Map(x => x.PONumber).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SONumber).Nullable();

        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria1).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria1").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria2).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria2").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria3).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria3").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria4).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria4").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria5).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria5").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteriaComment).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteriaComment").Nullable();

    }
```

No I have left out mapping the supplier side here as I was trying to simplify it best I could to be able to solve it.

So I don't understand why its having a issue... I've told it which column to look at (full name) not "RatingCriteria1"

as well as when I do have a variable RatingCriteria1 it has a getter and setter!!!

very odd... am i missing something you have to do when mapping sub classes like this?

Comment: How is the Rating class mapped to its table?

Comment: it is not a table, its just columns that exist on the Orders table.

Basically Orders table has many columns.. I want to model it so its 
Orders
Orders.BuyerRatings
Orders.SupplierRatings

But in the database its only one table called Orders

Comment: Then you will need to create a mapping to the Orders table for the Ratings class. NHibernate must be told how to fill a Rating class from teh database.

Comment: is that not what things like

 Map(x => x.BuyerRatings.RatingCriteria1).Column("EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria1").Nullable(); is doing?

Comment: No, each individual class that NHibernate is expected to be able to fill from the database will need to have a map.

Comment: Unfortunately, no; NHibernate won't know how to instantiate a Ratings object (or even that it has to) in order to fill it with the mapped projection, hence the error. You're going to have to either map Ratings, or flatten this object relation in the domain.

Comment: Then in your map for EnquiryOrder, you will map to a Ratings object for Buyer Ratings, and to one for Supplier Ratings

Comment: However, that will probably solve your problem; if you create a single Ratings object referenced by both Buyer and Supplier (or two subclasses of an abstract RatingsBase that map to the same columns on the same table) then you'll get what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map Ratings as a component, by doing:

```
public EnquiryOrderMapping()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("EnquiryOrderId");
    Map(x => x.DateOrdered);

    Map(x => x.PONumber).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.SONumber).Nullable();

    Component(x => x.BuyerRatings,
        y => 
            {
                y.Map(r => r.RatingCriteria1, "EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria1").Nullable();
                y.Map(r => r.RatingCriteria2, "EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria2").Nullable();
                y.Map(r => r.RatingCriteria3, "EnquiryBuyerRatingsRatingCriteria3").Nullable();
                // etc..
            });     
    // etc..
}
```